# Trying to create a shopping list template, need guidance adjusting line spacing

Tags: templates, itemize

I'm trying to get in the habit of planning out my meals more, and was looking for a template I could use to do so in LaTeX, but I couldn't find anything.

What I did find was an already-created pdf that looked like:
[image]

Which worked alright, but made me wish that there was something like this I could customize (for one, this list seems to be from the UK).

After looking around a little with some easier problems (turning bullet points into boxes), I was able to create the following image (I'll post my code at the bottom):
[image]

So far this seems to work alright, but two main problems I'm running into are: (1) getting the underline closer to the bottom of the box and (2) instead of just one column of lines where I can write in ingredients, it'd be nice to have two or three columns, since I generally found it was simpler to just write in what you needed, rather than hope it's on a pre-written list.

On top of all of those issues, if anyone has any input on how to make the list more user-friendly or more appealing, I'd love to hear it. Right now mine seems a little bland! As for my code... (I'm toying around with this project in a template that I use for other work that I do, so I know I'm using a variety of packages that I don't really need!)

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, array}
\usepackage{graphicx, fancyhdr, color}
\usepackage[bottom=1in, top=1in, left=.5in, right=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{tabto}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{firststyle} % This ensures that the header is only on page one
{
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{{\large Week of:\underline{\hspace{5cm}} \hspace{1cm} \textbf{B:} \hspace{1.5cm} \textbf{L:} \hspace{1.5cm} \textbf{D:} \hspace{1.5cm} \fbox{Cost: \hspace{2cm}}}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Removes the horizontal bar across the header
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage \\ \small{rev: \today}}

\newcommand\mydiv[2]{%
$\strut#1$\kern.25em\smash{\raise.3ex\hbox{$\big)$}}$\mkern-8mu
 \overline{\enspace\strut#2}$}

\newenvironment{tabbedenum}[1]
 {\NumTabs{#1}\inparaenum\let\latexitem\item
  \def\item{\def\item{\tab\latexitem}\latexitem}}
 {\endinparaenum}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{firststyle}

\setlength{\fboxrule}{1.5pt}

\framebox[2.5in][l]{ \parbox[t][1.5in]{1in}{} }
\framebox[2.5in][l]{ \parbox[t][1.5in]{1in}{
\begin{itemize} \itemsep-20pt
 \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\Box$} 
 \item  \underline{\hspace{2cm}} \\
 \item  \underline{\hspace{2cm}} \\
 \item  \underline{\hspace{2cm}} 
\end{itemize}

} }



\end{document}
```

Comment: Untested, but consider using `\rule[<depth>]{<width>}{<height>}`; say, `\rule[0.2cm]{2cm}{0.01cm}` --- which I'd wrap into a `\newcommand` for easier customizability.  The package `multicol` is useful for multicolumn stuff....

Comment: Note that the underlines are low because there is not enough space in the parbox for them to fit, so they are put on a new line. Try increasing the width of the second `parbox` (which is 1in in your code, 2in should be enough).

Comment: To have multiple columns, you can also put several `parbox` in the `framebox` (which should be larger for them to fit), each containing a list. The `multicol` package could also be used, but it might interfere with the `framebox` and the `itemize`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your primary problem was that your `\parbox` was wrapping, because you only made it 1 inch wide, but were placing the `\Box` plus a 2cm underline on it.  Thus, the underline was actually on the next line (there's a lesson here about mixing units).  Once that was resolved (by making the `\parbox` 1.2 inches wide), just adding extra `\parbox` invocations took care of it, in the form of the macro `\boxcol`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, array}
\usepackage{graphicx, fancyhdr, color}
\usepackage[bottom=1in, top=1in, left=.5in, right=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{tabto}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{firststyle} % This ensures that the header is only on page one
{
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{{\large Week of:\underline{\hspace{5cm}} \hspace{1cm} \textbf{B:} \hspace{1.5cm} \textbf{L:} \hspace{1.5cm} \textbf{D:} \hspace{1.5cm} \fbox{Cost: \hspace{2cm}}}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Removes the horizontal bar across the header
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage \\ \small{rev: \today}}

\newcommand\mydiv[2]{%
$\strut#1$\kern.25em\smash{\raise.3ex\hbox{$\big)$}}$\mkern-8mu
 \overline{\enspace\strut#2}$}

\newenvironment{tabbedenum}[1]
 {\NumTabs{#1}\inparaenum\let\latexitem\item
  \def\item{\def\item{\tab\latexitem}\latexitem}}
 {\endinparaenum}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\def\boxcol{%
\parbox[t][1.5in]{1.2in}{
\begin{itemize} \itemsep-15pt
 \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\Box$} 
 \item  \underline{\hspace{2cm}} \\
 \item  \underline{\hspace{2cm}} \\
 \item  \underline{\hspace{2cm}} \\
 \item  \underline{\hspace{2cm}} \\
 \item  \underline{\hspace{2cm}} 
\end{itemize}
}}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{firststyle}

\setlength{\fboxrule}{1.5pt}

\framebox[2.5in][l]{ \parbox[t][1.5in]{1in}{} }
\framebox[4in][l]{\boxcol\boxcol\boxcol }
\end{document}
```

[image]