# Templates for grocery list?

Tags: templates

I am looking for a LaTeX template for grocery lists. I’d like to create some standard list to check off if I am running out of something. I already saw the question [*Trying to create a shopping list template, need guidance adjusting line spacing*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196293/trying-to-create-a-shopping-list-template-need-guidance-adjusting-line-spacing) and think the right part of the pdf illustrates what I am looking for.

So, is there any template that might be a start?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So you are looking for a list with a box as the label item instead of the default circle? Everything you need for that can be found in the answer you linked to.

Comment: The answer in the question you linked to (by @StephenBSegletes) would seem to do what you want already. Just modify the `\def` of `\boxcol` to list your grocery items and how the definition is reused later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really you do not need any template, only the standard `itemize` environment and items with the optional argument (i.e, `\item[...]`) where you can change the dots by  your preferred check/checked box, for example:

```
\usepackage{amssymb} % in the preamble
% ....................................
\begin{itemize}
\item[$\square$] foo
\item[$\boxtime$] bar
\end{itemize}
```

Or

```
\usepackage{wasysym} % in the preamble
% ....................................
\begin{itemize}
\item[\CheckedBox] Cookies
\item[\Square] Coffee
\end{itemize}
```

Novices, dummies and lazy asses could find interesting make the check list with [Zim](http://zim-wiki.org/):

[image: mwe]

and then just export to LaTeX  (<kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Export</kbd> ... ) to obtain the wasysym's check list option.

However, if you want just edit LaTeX code but with a custom/easy check list environment, no problem:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xparse}
\def\pick{\item[\fboxsep0pt\fbox{\phantom{$\times$}}]}
\def\picked{\item[\fboxsep0pt\fbox{$\times$}]}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{shopping}{O{Shopping}}{%
\section*{\MakeUppercase #1  list}%
\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}}
\begin{document}

\begin{shopping}
    \pick Beer
    \pick Pizza 
    \picked  Chips
    \pick The \TeX book   
\end{shopping}

\begin{shopping}[tea time]
    \pick Tea 
    \pick Sugar 
    \pick Milk 
    \picked Cookies
    \picked Coffee
\end{shopping}

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]